# How is Cassandra able to efficiently binary-search variable-length rows in its SSTables?

Tags: database, cassandra, binary-search

From my understanding, Cassandra will allow different rows of a given table to have different lengths. This may happen as Cassandra allows one to have columns with maps and sets as its type, those structures containing an arbitrary number of elements (or if we're thinking in Thrift terms, we can have wide rows).

I also know that SSTables are storing records for a given table in sorted order, with a side index to aid in the binary-search process. It's very easy to understand how binary search would work in a world where every row in a table has the same length and all rows are stored sequentially on disk, but I'm confused as to how can it efficiently "jump" between records if they have variable length.

Edit: the only thing that comes to mind is if the index structure contains a reference to the beginning of every row, but then we would still have the same issue regarding finding a subset of columns (let's say, all the timestamps between A and B).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, from reading "Expert Apache Cassandra Administration (2018)", the index file contains (by default), the offset of every 128th key in the SSTable.

Cassandra is able to binary-search for a given key up to a granularity of 128 keys blocks and then, unfortunately, needs to linearly scan the SSTable from that offset on until it finds the key it's looking for.

Reference:

p124:

```
Index Files
An index file stores the offset of keys into the main data file, which is the SSTable. 
By default, the database stores a part of the index file in memory. 
The index file stores the offset for every 128th key in the SSTable, 
and you can configure this value.
```

p127:

```
5. The database first performs a binary search on the sample index
to find the starting offset into the index file. Using this offset, the
database offsets into the index file and performs a sequential read
to get the offset into the SSTable for the actual key.

6. Using the offset for the actual key, the database offsets into the
SSTable file and returns the actual data from the SSTable by
performing a lookup of the SSTable.
```